# class-transformer @Type() decorator doesn't work

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, class-validator, class-transformer

I have a dto file:

```
export class UpdateUserDto {
  @IsUUID()
  public readonly uuid: string;

  @IsObject()
  @Type(() => UserModelDto)
  public readonly dataToUpdate: UserModelDto;
}
```

The problem is, it seems @Type() decorator doesn't work. My UserModelDto looks like this:

```
export class UserModelDto {
  @IsUUID()
  @IsOptional()
  public uuid?: string;

  @IsEmail()
  @IsOptional()
  public email?: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  public password?: string;

  @IsJWT()
  @IsOptional()
  public refreshToken?: string;
}
```

When I send a request to a controller validation doesn't work for `dataToUpdate` field however for `uuid` it does. I've tried many ways but result remains the same.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you get an error? An absence of error? What are you expecting to happen vs what is happening?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel no, I'm not getting an error. The problem is, when I send request with 'dataToUpdate' property which contains wrong property - I can receive it in controller, but I shouldn't. For example: { uuid: '3049f15b-20ab-458d-80d1d9645c83c99f', dataToUpdate: { ttt: '3' } }. 'ttt' property doesn't exist in UserModelDto and I must receive a validation error, but request pass this validation and get to the controller

Comment: Are you using the `whitelist` and `forbidNonWhitelisted` options with `class-validator`?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel you are a bit late :) I've solved this problem exactly with whitelist and forbidNonWhitelisted options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure errors on validation when extra properties are sent in, you need to make use of the `forbidNonWhitelisted` option in the `ValidaitonPipe`. If you just want to strip the values you can use `transform: true` and `whitelist: true`

Answer (score 7):

You need to enable `{ transform: true }` inside the `ValidationPipe` options:

```
app.useGlobalPipes(
  new ValidationPipe({
    transform: true,
  }),
);
```

reference: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#transform-payload-objects

Comment: didn't help unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

You have forgot to add `@validateNested` decorator.

Comment: I've tried this way. It doesn't solve the problem